# Angular 2 Setup with Angular-CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I followed steps from angular.io to install angular-cli and create a base project.
It fails to serve or build every time. I removed npm, node, all node dep. still nothing. Getting the same error using different versions of angular-cli (beta28).

My `ng -v`

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.1
node: 6.10.0
os: darwin x64
@angular/common: 2.4.9
@angular/compiler: 2.4.9
@angular/core: 2.4.9
@angular/forms: 2.4.9
@angular/http: 2.4.9
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.9
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.9
@angular/router: 3.4.9
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.1
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.9
```

The errors I am getting:

```
ERROR in multi ./src/styles.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style-loader' in '/Users/sebastian/workspace/ellipsis/frontend'
 @ multi ./src/styles.css

ERROR in multi ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@ngtools/webpack' in '/Users/sebastian/workspace/ellipsis/frontend'
 @ multi ./src/main.ts

ERROR in multi ./src/polyfills.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@ngtools/webpack' in '/Users/sebastian/workspace/ellipsis/frontend'
     @ multi ./src/polyfills.ts
ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:
  Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'raw-loader' in '/Users/sebastian/workspace/ellipsis/frontend':
  Error: Can't resolve 'raw-loader' in '/Users/sebastian/workspace/ellipsis/frontend'
```

So I installed one by one all needed modules. But than I am left with another error which is no longer a missing module.

I don't think it should be necessary to install this modules one by one. What am I missing here?

Running OSX Sierra

Comment: Try running webpack --display-error-details. The error may not be related to file resolution.https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/981

Comment: Are you creating the project every time you re install angular-cli? Or you are using your own code base every time?

Comment: I am `rm -rf project-name` and `ng new project-name` cd -> `ng build`

Comment: have you tried update or use the > 6.9 version of node?

Comment: Is your local angular-cli version the same as your global cli version?

Comment: Please, publish some source code. 
It might not be related to the version of the angular-cli. Include your package.json as well.

Comment: Did you check the prerequisites? "Both the CLI and generated project have dependencies that require Node 6.9.0 or higher, together with NPM 3 or higher." Did you run  this command? "npm install -g @angular/cli"

Comment: @LatinWarrior yes I did... look in my question for version..

Comment: @StanleyKirdey What source code? I am using ng new <project_name>...

Answer (score 2):

use `@angular/cli` instead

```
npm uninstall angular-cli

npm cache clean

npm install @angular/cli

ng new myApp

ng serve
```

Comment: Getting exactly the same errors. I followed the steps from angular.io, yours are not much different, just reinstalling what I already had installed.

Comment: run these commands : `npm install style-loader` and `npm install @ngtools/webpack` and `npm install raw-loader`

Comment: Had to manually install bunch of other modules. All there, still errors:

`ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'newLine' of undefined
    at Object.getNewLineCharacter (/Users/sebastian/workspace/ellipsis/frontend/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:8062:20)
    at Object.createCompilerHost (/Users/sebastian/workspace/ellipsis/frontend/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:44978:26)
    at Object.ngcLoader (/Users/sebastian/workspace/ellipsis/frontend/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:338:33)
 @ multi ./src/main.ts`

Comment: @Trouble the above should be an edit to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are still using rc version of cli, I am using below versions, please check and update if anything differs

```
"angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.21",
"@angular/common": "~2.4.1",
"@angular/compiler": "~2.4.1",
"@angular/core": "~2.4.1",
"@angular/forms": "~2.4.1",
"@angular/http": "~2.4.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.1",
"@angular/router": "~3.1.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe if you clean the node modules and re install all should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you had an older version of Node.js installed and then  install the latest version.it will update the old version but still will be reffering old References.

Solution to this problem is to Uninstall older version of Node.js from add/remove
programs and install a fresh instance of latest Node.js.
then run "npm install -g @angular/cli" command prompt. it will install CLI components.